# How to reuse redis(JRedis) pool connection in Java

Tags: java, redis

I am using Redis(3.2.100) for Windows to cache my database data in Java.This is my redis init code:

```
private static Dictionary<Integer, JedisPool> pools = new Hashtable();

    static {
        JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
        config.setMaxIdle(2);
        config.setMaxTotal(10);
        config.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        config.setMaxWaitMillis(2000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JedisPool item  = new JedisPool(config, "127.0.0.1", 6379,10*1000);
            pools.put(i, item);
        }
    }
```

This is the cache code:

```
public static String get(String key, Integer db) {
        JedisPool poolItem = pools.get(db);
        Jedis jredis = poolItem.getResource();
        String result = jredis.get(key);
        return result;
    }
```

The problem is when the program run for a while,the getResource method throws:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

So how to reuse the connection or close the connection.I am using this command to find out that the client has reached the max value.

```
D:\Program Files\Redis>redis-cli.exe info clients
# Clients
connected_clients:11
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
```

How to fix it?

Comment: the JedisException should be thrown because of a NosuchElementException. can u give more information about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to close the redis connection,modify this function like this:

```
public static String get(String key, Integer db) {
        JedisPool poolItem = pools.get(db);
        Jedis jredis = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            jredis = poolItem.getResource();
            result = jredis.get(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("get value error", e);
        } finally {
            if (jredis != null) {
                jredis.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```